# Finite universal numbers

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Given an alphabel $\Sigma$, a sequence $\bar{s}$ in $\Sigma^*$ is said to be **k-universal** if it contains all sub-sequences of $\Sigma^k$. I am interested by the smallest of these k-universal sequences. Of course, it should have length at least $|\Sigma|^k + k - 1$. Empirically, there are a lot of k-universal sequences of this length.

For example, for $\Sigma = \{0, 1\}$ and $k = 3$, a few of these sequences are `0001011100`, `0001110100` and `0010111000`. Each of them has a length of $10 = 2^3 + 3 - 1$ and contains all the sub-sequences `000`, `001`, `010`, `011`, `100`, `101`, `110` and `111`.

**Is there a fast way to find smallest k-universal sequences, even just one?**

*What I've tried*

Looking for such sequences with a binary alphabet $\Sigma = \{0, 1\}$, I found out that we could model this problem as finding an Hamiltonian path (going through all vertices) on an oriented graph G(V, E), where the vertices V are the sequences of $\Sigma^k$ and for each $x,y \in \Sigma, \bar{s} \in \Sigma^{k-1}$, there is an edge $(x\bar{s}) \to (\bar{s}y) \in$ E.
For $k = 1, 2, 3, 4$, I rendered manually the graphs below:

[image: Graph for k=1]

[image: Graph for k=2]

[image: Graph for k=3]

[image: Graph for k=4]

However, computing an Hamiltonian path is an NP-complete problem in general, and after implementing it this solution does not scale. Is there a more generative way to obtain the smallest k-universal numbers, e.g. with grammars?

Comment: They are called [De Bruijn sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence#Construction). That page lists some construction methods.

Comment: For binary, the [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#Constructing_an_n-bit_Gray_code) is a simple way to find one.   Later the article shows how to construct one for ternary.

Comment: @RossMillikan Gray codes are not what I want. They transform numbers by exactly one digit anywhere in the number, whereas I shift the digits and insert a new one. JaapSherphuis This is exactly what I wanted.